Prove that $n!>n^k$ for all $n\ge 2k$
To make my question more clear.
From David M. Burton Elementary Number Theory Problems 1.1. Exercises 6)*, we know already, that the following two propositions are true and proveable by induction.
$n! > n^2$ for all $n\ge 4$
$n!>n^3$ for all $n\ge 6$
I would like to state and prove a general case for all powers of $n^k$.
$n! > n^k$ for all $n \ge 2k$ and $k \ge 2$

Is stated proposition an apropriate generalization"?
If yes, how could it be proved?
If not, why and can the problem be stated differently?

Thank you again

I think you mix up the problem. In particular, they are just two separated problems (Check back the actual statement). Moreover, some terminology problem is that the base case refer to the starting $k$, that is $k=4$ in the first inequality, and $k=6$ in the inequality.

The statement is not true for all $k$. For $k=1$, it does not hold that $n!>n$ for all $n \geq 2$ counter example, $n=2$

@EdmaandVladPhiyik Since in the problems from the book $k=2$ and $3$, the OP obviously assumes that $k\ge 2$.

Poor question. It seems like self-promotion. I did that I . No you  haven't contributed anything new on this topic. It's a basic engineering question, more appropriate for high school level.

@EdmaandVladPhiyik, I assumed from the context that it's clear that k must be >= 2 and therefore n starts at $n>=2k>=4$ for $k=2$ and thus $n^k = n^2$

@Riemann'sLastTheorem0bq.com Yes it is a very basic question, that's why I am still not past the first chapter of Elementary Number Theory and thought I could receive some help rather than a rant. I mentioned my background just to give some context, I even asked for forgiveness, as i am aware, that my mathematical resoining and language may not be completely formal.

$$(n!)^2 = (1 \cdot n) (2 \cdot (n-1)) (3 \cdot (n-2)) \cdots
((n-2) \cdot 3) ((n-1) \cdot 2) (n \cdot 1)
\ge n^n$$ $$\implies n!>n^{\frac n2}\geq n^k,\forall n\geq2k,k\geq2.$$

@Riemann thank you very much, I see now, that my assumption coined in my terms $n>=2k$ was plain wrong in the first place.

Consider that, in the real domain, you want to find the zero of function
$$f(n)=\log (\Gamma (n+1))-k \log (n)$$ for which
$$f'(n)=\psi(n+1)-\frac{k}{n}$$
Using Stirling approximation
$$f'(n)=\log (n)+\frac{1-2 k}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ So, an approximation of the minimum is
$$n_*=\frac{2 k-1}{2 W\left(\frac{2 k-1}{2}\right)}$$ where $W(.)$ is the principal branch of Lambert function.
For example, if $k=5$, this approximation gives $n_*=3.55103$ while the solution is $3.56127$.
Just as a random guess, use $n_0=2n_*$ and perform one single iteration of Newton-like methods; the formulae are nasty but fully explicit.
Some results in the real domain
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
k & \text{Newton}& \text{Halley}& \text{Householder}& \text{solution}\\
 2 & 3.61713 & 3.57136 & 3.56396 &  3.56238 \\
 3 & 5.04070 & 5.03687 & 5.03673 &  5.03672 \\
 4 & 6.47175 & 6.46413 & 6.46448 &  6.46447 \\
 5 & 7.90980 & 7.85679 & 7.86252 &  7.86192 \\
 6 & 9.35411 & 9.21949 & 9.24063 &  9.23754 \\
 7 & 10.8040 & 10.5563 & 10.6051 &  10.5964 \\
 8 & 12.2588 & 11.8704 & 11.9601 &  11.9418 \\
 9 & 13.7182 & 13.1646 & 13.3086 &  13.2761 \\
 10 & 15.1817 & 14.4409 & 14.6527 &  14.6011 \\
 11 & 16.6489 & 15.7013 & 15.9939 &  15.9179 \\
 12 & 18.1196 & 16.9472 & 17.3336 &  17.2277 \\
 13 & 19.5935 & 18.1798 & 18.6725 &  18.5312 \\
 14 & 21.0704 & 19.4003 & 20.0115 &  19.8291 \\
 15 & 22.5501 & 20.6097 & 21.3511 &  21.122 \\
 16 & 24.0324 & 21.8086 & 22.6918 &  22.4103 \\
 17 & 25.5172 & 22.9978 & 24.0340 &  23.6944 \\
 18 & 27.0043 & 24.1781 & 25.3780 &  24.9746 \\
 19 & 28.4937 & 25.3498 & 26.7240 &  26.2514 \\
 20 & 29.9851 & 26.5136 & 28.0724 &  27.5248 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Using the ceiling
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
k & \text{Newton}& \text{Halley}& \text{Householder}& \text{solution}\\
 2 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
 3 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 \\
 4 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 \\
 5 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 \\
 6 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 \\
 7 & 11 & 11 & 11 & 11 \\
 8 & 13 & 12 & 12 & 12 \\
 9 & 14 & 14 & 14 & 14 \\
 10 & 16 & 15 & 15 & 15 \\
 11 & 17 & 16 & 16 & 16 \\
 12 & 19 & 17 & 18 & 18 \\
 13 & 20 & 19 & 19 & 19 \\
 14 & 22 & 20 & 21 & 20 \\
 15 & 23 & 21 & 22 & 22 \\
 16 & 25 & 22 & 23 & 23 \\
 17 & 26 & 23 & 25 & 24 \\
 18 & 28 & 25 & 26 & 25 \\
 19 & 29 & 26 & 27 & 27 \\
 20 & 30 & 27 & 29 & 28 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Edit
For the solution in the real domain, using a bit of heuristics and asymptotic analysis, it seems that
$$n \sim \frac 65 k+\frac 43 \log(k)-\frac 14$$
For $k=100$ this would give $n=125.89$ while the solution is $125.24$.

Okay, now I see, that I was plain wrong. What seemed to be a solid assumption $n>=2k$ is plain wrong. If I had tested a few other values for n and k beforehand, I would have seen, that my assumption doesn#t hold.

@muritz. Who never made a mistake ? Not me for sure. I'm not throwing stones at you. Cheers & thanks for the interesting problem.
